# Reduce memory leaks in php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php script that is called by a shortcode in WordPress. It runs fine for a bit but eventually leads to my server crashing.

On its own the script takes up 3mb of memory(tested using `get_memory_peak_usage`)

However the issue arises because it is a shortcode and it can be placed it 3,4, even 5 different places on one page.

For example if I wanted to have the user name displayed in the navigation bar, beside their avatar, and even have a little message "Welcome {username}" I would have to place a shortcode 3 times.

I need to reduce the amount of memory 1 run of the script takes up to nearly nothing.

SO the very first thing I tried when the server first crashed was free up the variables which looks a little something like this

I created a function to set the variable to null and then unset it

```php
function DestroyVar($var){
    $var = null;
    unset($var);
}
```

and then I updated my code so after each one was done being used it was "Destroyed"

```php
function ParseUserAvatar($uid,$style = null){
            global $wpdb;

            $query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id=$uid AND meta_key='wp_user_avatar'");
      $result = $query->meta_value;

      mysqli_free_result($query);
      $this->DestroyVar($query);

            $decoded_data = unserialize($result);
      $this->DestroyVar($result);
            $src = $decoded_data[0]["avatar_url"];

            $this->DestroyVar($decoded_data);

            if(empty($src) || $src == null || $src == ''){
                $src = "https:////www.gravatar.com/avatar/24d7a56b7fbacec3ee5701d7ee5130e3?s=150&f=y&r=g";
            }

            $html = '';
            $html .= '
                <style>
                .dm-avatar-origin {
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    width: 212px;
                    height: 212px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                }
                </style>
            ';

            if($style == null){
                $html .= '<img src="'.$src.'" alt="Avatar" class="dm-avatar-origin dm-avatar uap-member-photo">';
            }else{
                $html .= '<img src="'.$src.'" alt="Avatar" class="dm-avatar-origin uap-member-photo ' . $style . '">';
            }

            $this->DestroyVar($src);

            return $html;
        }
```

This didn't reduce the memory usage as much as I had hoped (50k->45k)

So I then started to reduce the amount of `vars` being created so my script now looked like this

```php
function ParseUserAvatar($uid,$style = null){
            global $wpdb;

            $query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id=$uid AND meta_key='wp_user_avatar'")->meta_value;

            $decoded_data = unserialize($query);
            mysqli_free_result($query);
            $this->DestroyVar($query);
            $src = $decoded_data[0]["avatar_url"];

            $this->DestroyVar($decoded_data);

            if(empty($src) || $src == null || $src == ''){
                $src = "https:////www.gravatar.com/avatar/24d7a56b7fbacec3ee5701d7ee5130e3?s=150&f=y&r=g";
            }

            $html = '';
            $html .= '
                <style>
                .dm-avatar-origin {
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    width: 212px;
                    height: 212px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                }
                </style>
            ';

            if($style == null){
                $html .= '<img src="'.$src.'" alt="Avatar" class="dm-avatar-origin dm-avatar uap-member-photo">';
            }else{
                $html .= '<img src="'.$src.'" alt="Avatar" class="dm-avatar-origin uap-member-photo ' . $style . '">';
            }

            $this->DestroyVar($src);

            return $html;
        }
```

At this point I do not know how I can reduce the memory usage any further and it still crashes my server

Comment: So perhaps using a Singleton trait would be a better idea than re-loading multiple instances.. Create a single static instance where the data is loaded once, then place it on the pages in their place

Comment: I'm not as familiar with WP as other frameworks, but a common solution to something like this would be to implement caching in your function. So at the top you'd check if this variable is already set, and if so then return that value. That way your function really only does the heavy lifting once, but will always return that save value anytime it's called. If WP has a caching library, then you likely can utilize a key:value pair (ex: you can concat `$uuid.$style` parameters and then hash it to determine the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is a [demo](https://3v4l.org/JGiGp) of this done when loading multiple avatars (IE: Many users avatars)

Rather than reloading multiple queries (multiple transactions) on a large data set, you can create a static instance and then access the data there-after.

You can achieve this by creating a trait for your class to use like so.

```
trait Singleton {
    private static $_instance;

    public static function getInstance() {
        # If the instance has already been created, use the object
        if(self::$_instance) return self::$_instance;

        # If this is a first time call, create the instance
        self::$_instance = new self();
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}
}
```

You then can simply load that data inside your `__construct` callback thus only loading the data once, then create a getter method to retrieve the data.

```
class Avatar {
    use Singleton;

    private $_data;

    private function __construct() {
        /**
         * $this->_data = your query result (enter logic here)
         */
    }

    public function getData() { return $this->_data; }
}
```

To now display it anywhere on the page, you can simply use the static instance like so:

```
Avatar::getInstance()->getData()
```

Since the `$_instance` is set after the first call, it always returns the object with the generated data. Only 1 transaction is made to the Database.

Ofc, this is only a placeholder. You would need to update the methods to contain the correct arguments and logic you need.

**Update:**

Your `destoryVar` method is void. PHP variables are not passed by reference by default thus the method contains arguments in its own scope.

To make that method work, you can use `&` to pass by reference. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Xa8DVU)

```
function destoryVar(&$var) { ... }
```

Comment: Wordpress calls the data onto the page through a shortcode so I wouldnt be able to grab it in the construct

Comment: it goes Page->Shortcode->Method->Class->Method the page contains the shortcode which calls the function to access the class to call the method to return the avatar

Comment: How not? You could pass it into the `getInstance` method as an argument. @CoderJoe

Comment: The class also contains several other methods as well

Comment: Also, your `destoryVar` method is void as seen [here](https://3v4l.org/3bjKS). The passed in argument contains a different scope. You need to pass it in by reference: `function destoryVar(&var)` as seen [here](https://3v4l.org/Xa8DVU) @CoderJoe